# Can I ask for feedback on the graphics of the reverse side of my business card here?

Tags: discussion

I have designed a business card, and I want to ask for feedback on color combinations that I can use on the reverse side.

I can paste front and reverse side here for more clarity in the question. But I dont want to right away since I dont want to sound like I am publicizing my product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feedback questions are typically closed (examples [1](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/5101/8708), [2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/5212/8708)), but they are not concretely off topic. See this dusty old post for pointers on how to ask a good critique question: [Asking community to critique work?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26/8708)

If it's just feedback on color combinations, I'm not sure there's enough substance there to keep it from getting closed. However, there have been a few questions that I've seen that are similar to what you may be aiming for:

- [Matching colors for dark brown](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17264/8708)
- [Are there any color palette choosing tools that make it easy to incorporate black/gray/white?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/16802/8708)

If you can phrase the question in such a way that it will be beneficial to other users and not just yourself, then I say go for it.

If you think it will help, feel free to update your post with the front and reverse sides. As long as it's not something like ***CLICK HERE FOR NEAR-REAL ROLEX WATCHES*** then I don't see it as an issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about it.

Comment: @JohnB Is it alright to post critique questions in the Chat?

Comment: @ckpepper02, absolutely! Our chat is very laid back. I don't even think GD.SE's chat has any specific rules set out (yet?), so hop in and tell us what you had for breakfast if you're bored :)